# Parsing YAML Front Matter with PHP

Tags: php, yaml

I have [YAML Front Matter](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/yaml-front-matter) that I want to parse with PHP:

```
---
title = A nice title goes here
tags = tag1 tag2 tag3
---
This is the content of this entry...
Line2
Line3
```

I know it's about a Ruby gem of some kind, but I want use this in PHP to create a user-friendly flatfile blog engine.

I also have a snippet from a project called Phrozn. Maybe it can be handy for you guys to see it in order to help me with the problem as best as possible.

```
private function parse()
{
    if (isset($this->template, $this->frontMatter)) {
        return $this;
    }

    $source = $this->readSourceFile();

    $parts = preg_split('/[\n]*[-]{3}[\n]/', $source, 2);
    if (count($parts) === 2) {
        $this->frontMatter = Yaml::load($parts[0]);
        $this->template = trim($parts[1]);
    } else {
        $this->frontMatter = null;
        $this->template = trim($source);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: How is this different than [PHP YAML Parsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294355/php-yaml-parsers)?

Comment: Because ordinary YAML parsers worn't allow multiple languages in the same file.

Comment: So you want a little bit of YAML at the top and the rest as non-YAML? Sorry, I misunderstood your intent. What part of that `parse` function doesn't work?

Comment: That's okay. I think it's the regex format. It works fine when used in the other project (Phrozn), but I can't get it to work here. I am trying to split the document and get rid of the "\n"'s that shouldn't be there, so I end up with the two varibles that doesn't contain unnecessary spaces and newlines. Would I be better going with an alternative method? Please see this link: http://www.phrozn.info/en/documentation/front-matter/. If you want to help me make this open-source YAML Front-Matter snippet-project, maybe we can help those who had been looking for such solution, just like myself. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that you're trying to split the something with **three** parts into **two** parts. If you drop the third argument to [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), you'll get an array with three elements. The first piece of this (when delimited by `---`):

```
---
title = A nice title goes here
tags = tag1 tag2 tag3
---
This is the content of this entry...
Line2
Line3
```

Is empty, the second is the YAML, and third is the content. Try this:

```
$parts = preg_split('/[\n]*[-]{3}[\n]/', $source, 3);
```

And a live test case: http://ideone.com/LYLxZ

If you want to match what Phrozn seems to be doing then your input would look like this:

```
title = A nice title goes here
tags = tag1 tag2 tag3
---
This is the content of this entry...
Line2
Line3
```

And your PHP would be this:

```
$parts = preg_split('/[\n]*[-]{3}[\n]/', $source, 2);
```

And a live test case for this version: http://ideone.com/a9a6C

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :)

It works, but when I replace the current $source variable with "$source = file_get_contents("../entries/13-08-11-23-41-hashtag.txt");", then it doesn't work. I think it's because of the \n's. I also think this can be solved easily, but just can't figure it out. Do you have a quick solution on this?

Comment: @Robbie: What's different about what `file_get_contents` returns? Is there maybe an end-of-line CR-LF issue? Sorry for the delays but at least I'm making up for the erroneous close-vote.

Comment: If you use the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag `preg_split` will match both  of these yaml cases.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and was quite unhappy with an untested regex and the rare packages that were available.

I wrote a library (Composer, TDD, PSR-4) to handle that. The library also handles parsing the YAML *and* the Markdown: **[FrontYAML](https://github.com/mnapoli/FrontYAML)**

The YAML and Markdown parser can be overridden. By default, Symfony YAML and Parsedown are used.

Answer (score 0):

I did it thus:

```
// $string contains the full file.

$split = preg_split("/[\n]*[-]{3}[\n]/", $string, 3, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
try {
  // Strip extra, non-indentation, whitespace from beginning of lines
  $i = 0; $yfm = "";
  while ($split[0][$i] == " ") {$i++;}
  foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $split[0]) as $line){
    $yfm .= substr($line, $i) . "\n";
  }
  // Using symfony's YAML parser
  $data = sfYaml::load($yfm);
} catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
  // This is not YAML
}
```

It removes the extraneous indentation one might get which would trip the parser, and it converts all newlines, whether they be Win (CRLF), Nix (LF), or Mac (CR), to just `"\n"`.