# Email read in PHP

Tags: php, regex, database, email

I need to read fields from this `email`

```
MOVE INFORMATION

Pickup Address: 34 Marigold Ln, Marlboro, NJ 07746

Delivery Address: 180 Prospect Park W, Apt 5, Brooklyn, NY 11215

Primary service dates:
Pack Date: N/A
Move Date: 6/6/2013

Other service dates:
Pack Date 2: N/A
Move Date2: N/A
Other Date: N/A
```

The process I am following is:

1. Connect through IMAP
2. get the nessage body

Now I want to read specified data and need to convert it into array like:

```
array( ' Pickup Address'=>'34 Marigold Ln, Marlboro, NJ 07746', 
       'Delivery Address'=>'180 Prospect Park W, Apt 5, Brooklyn, NY 11215'...)
```

I have tried `preg_match('/(?P<Pickup Address>\w+): (?P<Delivery Address>\d+)/', $body, $matches)`

but thats having some problem:

1. It is not accepting space in 'Pickup Address'
2. it is providing array in `Array ( [0] => Address: 34 [PickupAddress] => Address [1] => Address [DeliveryAddress] => 34 [2] => 34 )` format.

Basically I need to save these fields in database and I can not use attachment here. Let me know if you have any other solution or any way to make it work

Comment: Order and format will be same every time? means first Pickup address then delivery address and so on?

Comment: Yes!The fields name would remain same their values would vary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
$string = 'MOVE INFORMATION

Pickup Address: 34 Marigold Ln, Marlboro, NJ 07746

Delivery Address: 180 Prospect Park W, Apt 5, Brooklyn, NY 11215

Primary service dates:
Pack Date: N/A
Move Date: 6/6/2013

Other service dates:
Pack Date 2: N/A
Move Date2: N/A
Other Date: N/A';

preg_match_all('#(.*?):(.*)#m', $string, $m);
if(isset($m[1], $m[2])){
    $array = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
    print_r($array);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Pickup Address] =>  34 Marigold Ln, Marlboro, NJ 07746
    [Delivery Address] =>  180 Prospect Park W, Apt 5, Brooklyn, NY 11215
    [Primary service dates] => 
    [Pack Date] =>  N/A
    [Move Date] =>  6/6/2013
    [Other service dates] => 
    [Pack Date 2] =>  N/A
    [Move Date2] =>  N/A
    [Other Date] =>  N/A
)
```

Comment: What if right values also has ":" character, will this handle it?

Comment: Like Pickup Address: 34 Marigold Ln, Marlboro:NJ 07746

Comment: It has issue, if right values have new line characters, it reads only first line.

Comment: @IrfanDANISH Yes, ofcourse. Otherwise how would you differentiate between left and right or if it's a valid string you want to enter ?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have chosen a solution then are having difficulty making it fit the problem. Yes you could use regexes - but you're going to have to define the problem a lot better than you already have. What if a line contains more than one ':'? What about blank lines? What if a data item spans more than one line (which it might do depending on how the email is encoded)?

While you could use a [YAML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294355/php-yaml-parsers), it's probably overkill for a simple layout:

```
$data=array();
while ($line=fgets($file_handle)) {
     $key=trim(substr($line, 0, strpos($line, ':')));
     $value=trim(substr($line, strpos($line, ':')+1));
     if ($key && $value) $data[$key]=$value; 
}
```

Comment: I like this, people tend to think that regex is the solution to everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use code like this:

```
preg_match_all("/(Pickup Address|Delivery Address): *(.*)/", $email, $match);
$result = array();
foreach($match[1] as $i => $key) {
    $result[$key] = $match[2][$i];
}
print_r($result);
```

if you want more fields just add them to the regex.