# Reading text after a certain character in php

Tags: php, explode

Okay so I have a text file and inside of the text file I have these lines:

```
IP = 127.0.0.1
EXE = Client.exe
PORT = 8080
TITLE = Title
MAINT = False
MAINT-Message = This is the message.
```

what I am wanted to do is get the 'False' part on the fifth line.

I have the basic concept but I can't seem to make it work. This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('LauncherInfo.txt');
$info = explode(' = ', $file);

echo $info[5];
?>
```

And with this I get a result but when I echo $info[5] it gives me 'False Maint-Message' so it splits it but it only splits at the = sign. I want to be able to make it split at the where I have pressed enter to go onto the next line. Is this possible and how can I do it?

I was thinking it would work if I make it explode on line one and then do the same for the second line with a loop until it came to the end of the file? I don't know how to do this though.

Thanks.

Comment: If you use file() instead of file_get_contents() you'll have an array that you can iterate over, or reference by line number (-1) as the array key

Comment: Don't use `explode` at all. Consider a regex, or parse_ini_file.

Comment: if you use parese_ini_file, be aware that `False` will return an empty string

Comment: Just use my answer [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17297209) and change the pattern to `#(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*)#m`

Comment: Thanks guys. There are different methods of doing it. I see now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the file(), which splits a file's contents into an array of the file's lines.

Try this:

```
$file = file('LauncherInfo.txt');
foreach ($file as $line) {
    if ($line) {
        $splitLine = explode(' = ',$line);
        $data[$splitLine[0]] = $splitLine[1];
    }
}
echo $data['MAINT'];
```

Comment: Oh that works. Thank you very much. Was looking into it for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you were curious, since I wasn't aware of the file() function. You could do it manually like this

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('LauncherInfo.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
$info=array();
foreach($lines as $line){
  $split=explode(' = ',$line);
  $info[]=$splitline[1];
}
echo $info[5];//prints False
?>
```