# How to manipulate Text File in PHP

Tags: php, text

I have a text file that looks like below:

[image]

Is there a way to echo particular characters only per line?

- 29 characters that starts with "9954" value
- Last 13 characters of the line

My code to display the text file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
echo "<pre>".file_get_contents("MAGFLE_Greenbnk_Caraga.txt")."</pre>";
?>
```

Your help will be very much appreciated 
Thank You

Comment: How are those columns separated? With tabs?

Comment: Use `file()` to read the file into an array of lines. Loop through the array, extracting the parts that you want using a regular expression.

Comment: Or use a `while($line = fgets($fp))` loop to read one line at a time from the file, and then do the same thing.

Comment: There must be hundreds of tutorials on how to read from a file in PHP. Please make some effort to learn on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Use a multiline regular expression and loop over all matches:

```
$source = file_get_contents("MAGFLE_Greenbnk_Caraga.txt");
$matches = [];

preg_match_all("/(9954[0-9]{25}).*(.{13}$)/um", $source, $matches);

for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); ++$i) {
    echo "Line {$i} -- ";
    echo "chars that start with '9954': {$matches[1][$i]} --- ";
    echo "last 13 chars: {$matches[2][$i]} <br>";
}
```

The regular expression contains two capture groups. The first group matches the 29 characters starting with '6654'. The second one matches the last 13 characters.

The matches array contains 3 arrays:

- The first array contains all matched lines
- The second array contains all matches from the first capture group
- The third array contains all matches from the second capture group

I get the following output when applying your data:

[image: result]

Depending on your data this will not work in all cases. Maybe you have to enhance the regex with more rules.

Answer (score -2):

You can store the .txt data in an array and then sort as you please. The explode() function should help. Link given below -

[Reading text after a certain character in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330591/reading-text-after-a-certain-character-in-php)