# How to json_decode invalid JSON with apostrophe instead of quotation mark

Tags: php, json

Sample code:

```
<?php

$json = "['foo', 'bar']";

var_dump( json_decode($json) );
```

<strike>It works with **PHP 5.5.3** but it fails for lower PHP's versions</strike>

It works on my machine with PHP 5.5.3 but it fails everywhere else.

I know it is incorrect JSON but my webservice gives me JSON with `'` symbols together with `"`

```
['foo', "bar", {'test': "crazy \"markup\""}]
```

[Sandbox](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OfhDXL)

How to parse JSON data with apostrophes in PHP 5.3? **Obviously original JSON I want to parse is more complex.**

(I can't upgrade my PHP on production server neither get proper JSON from webservice)

Comment: IMHO, ff PHP/5.5.3 parses invalid JSON it's probably a bug.

Comment: It appears your code sample doesn't work for any version, http://3v4l.org/Hl99u

Comment: What does the broken webservice return if a string contains `"` or `'`? Have you let the service know they're serving bad json?

Comment: @AnthonySterling it works for `PHP 5.5.3-1ubuntu2 (cli)`

Comment: @Eric sometimes it uses `'`, sometimes `"`

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past with providers that would send invalid XML. In the end, I had to use string manipulation functions to fix errors as I discover them before the actual parsing.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. When a json string _value_ contains either type of quote, are they escaped?

Comment: Unfortunately invalid data is a big problem, my 0,02 cent is talk with the provider if you can, I had also XML troubles and had to do a lot of text parsing to fix their invalid formatting (for example they used non escaped ampersands).

Comment: @Eric: it's crazy mix like `['foo', {"bar": "hel'lo", "foo": 'ba"r'}]`

Comment: Is this a real example ? How this (`["foo", 'bar', {'test': "hello \" world"}]`) is going to be a valid string within `quotes`, can you echo this `json` string ?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575198/invalid-json-parsing-using-php).

Comment: @SheikhHeera no it's not, sorry. just imagine mix quotes / apostrophes

Comment: As a bad hack, wouldn't it work if you first escape (replace) " with \" and then replace all ' by "?

Comment: @Sheikh it doesn't work http://codepad.viper-7.com/GRgr2m

Comment: @Tobi unfortunately it's a mix of " and '

Comment: The glyphs are are colloquially known in both PHP, and Javascript as single and double quotes — calling them apostrophe and quotation marks is confusing: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/string

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Here's an alternative solution to this problem:

```
function fixJSON($json) {
    $regex = <<<'REGEX'
~
    "[^"\\]*(?:\\.|[^"\\]*)*"
    (*SKIP)(*F)
  | '([^'\\]*(?:\\.|[^'\\]*)*)'
~x
REGEX;

    return preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) {
        return '"' . preg_replace('~\\\\.(*SKIP)(*F)|"~', '\\"', $matches[1]) . '"';
    }, $json);
}
```

This approach is more robust than h2ooooooo's function in two respects:

- It preserves double quotes occurring in a single quoted string, by applying additional escaping to them. h2o's variant will replace them with double quotes instead, thus changing the value of the string.
- It will properly handle escaped double quotes `\"`, for which h2o's version seems to go into an infinite loop.

Test:

```
$brokenJSON = <<<'JSON'
['foo', {"bar": "hel'lo", "foo": 'ba"r ba\"z', "baz": "wor\"ld ' test"}]
JSON;

$fixedJSON = fixJSON($brokenJSON);
$decoded = json_decode($fixedJSON);

var_dump($fixedJSON);
print_r($decoded);
```

Output:

```
string(74) "["foo", {"bar": "hel'lo", "foo": "ba\"r ba\"z", "baz": "wor\"ld ' test"}]"
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bar] => hel'lo
            [foo] => ba"r ba"z
            [baz] => wor"ld ' test
        )
)
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for nested objects though.

Comment: It does not handle cases e.g. `\'` inside single quoted string.

This will fail: `{'a':'\''}`

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple parser that'll fix your quotes for you.  If it encounters a `'` quote which isn't in a double quote `"`, it'll assume that it's wrong and replace the double quotes inside of that quote, and turn the quote enclosured into double quotes:

**Example**:

```
<?php
    function fixJSON($json) {
        $newJSON = '';

        $jsonLength = strlen($json);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $jsonLength; $i++) {
            if ($json[$i] == '"' || $json[$i] == "'") {
                $nextQuote = strpos($json, $json[$i], $i + 1);
                $quoteContent = substr($json, $i + 1, $nextQuote - $i - 1);
                $newJSON .= '"' . str_replace('"', "'", $quoteContent) . '"';
                $i = $nextQuote;
            } else {
                $newJSON .= $json[$i];
            }
        }

        return $newJSON;
    }

    $brokenJSON = "['foo', {\"bar\": \"hel'lo\", \"foo\": 'ba\"r'}]";
    $fixedJSON = fixJSON( $brokenJSON );

    var_dump($fixedJSON);

    print_r( json_decode( $fixedJSON ) );
?>
```

**Output**:

```
string(41) "["foo", {"bar": "hel'lo", "foo": "ba'r"}]"
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bar] => hel'lo
            [foo] => ba'r
        )

)
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/XdmeOAAL)

Answer (score 4):

[NikiCs´ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385378/nikic) is already spot on. Your input seems to be manually generated, so it's entirely possible that within `'` single quoted strings, you'll receive unquoted `"` doubles. A regex [assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json) is therefore advisable instead of a plain search and replace.

But there are also a few userland JSON parsers which support a bit more Javascript expression syntax. It's probably best to speak of *JSOL*, JavaScript Object Literals, at this point.

#### PEARs [Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON)

Services_JSON can decode:

- unquoted object keys
- and strings enclosed in single quotes.

No additional options are required, just `= (new Services_JSON)->decode($jsol);`

#### up_json_decode() in [upgradephp](http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/)

This was actually meant as fallback for early PHP versions without JSON extension. It reimplements PHPs [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode). But there's also the `upgrade.php.prefixed` version, which you'd use here.
It introduces an additional flag `JSON_PARSE_JAVASCRIPT`.

```
up_json_decode($jsol, false, 512, JSON_PARSE_JAVASCRIPT);
```

And I totally forgot about mentionind this in the docs, but it also supports single-quoted strings.
For instance:

```
{ num: 123, "key": "value", 'single': 'with \' and unquoted " dbls' }
```

Will decode into:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [num] => 123
    [key] => value
    [single] => with ' and unquoted " double quotes
)
```

### Other options

- [JasonDecoder](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Lexers/JasonDecoder.php) by [@](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Lexers/JasonDecoder.php)ArtisticPhoenix does support unquoted keys and literals, though no `'`-quoted strings. It's easy to understand or extend however.
- YAML (1.2) is a superset of JSON, and most [parsers](https://packagist.org/?query=yaml) support both unquoted keys or single-quoted strings. See also [PHP YAML Parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294355/php-yaml-parsers)

Obviously any JSOL tokenizer/parser in userland is measurably slower than just preprocessing malformed JSON. If you expect no further gotchas from your webservice, go for the regex/quote conversion instead.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to build a proxy using NodeJS. NodeJS will handle the faulty JSON just fine and return a clean version:

```
johan:~ # node
> JSON.stringify(['foo', 'bar']);
'["foo","bar"]'
```

Maybe write a simple Node script that accepts the JSON data as STDIN and returns the validated JSON to STDOUT. That way you can call it from PHP.

The downside is that your server would need NodeJS. Not sure if that is a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that PHP 5.5.+ will parse this JSON gracefully, I would pipe the web service responses trough a proxy script on a PHP5.5+ web server, which sanitizes the responses for lower versions - meaning just `echo json_encode(json_decode($response))`; That's a stable and reliable approach.

If you make the web service URL configurable trough a config value, it will work for lower versions by accessing the proxy, in higher versions by accessing the web service directly.

Answer (score 1):

A fast solution could be `str_replace("'","\"",$string)`. This depends on many things, but I think you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (and probably modify/extend) a library to build an AST from the supplied JSON and replace the single quotes with double quotes.

https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint/blob/master/src/Seld/JsonLint/Lexer.php

Might be a good start.