# PHP string presented as array to array

Tags: php

```
$var = "['test', 'test2', 'test3']";
```

how do I create a workable array from this in PHP?

I've tried explode($var, ","); but this didn't seem to work, unless something went wrong with that attempt.

Comment: It's always a bad idea to store code in strings like this! `$myArray = str_getcsv(trim($var, '[]'), ',', "'");`

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't just json_decode that?

Comment: Ah yeah, singlequotes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode($var, ",");` is wrong. `explode` needs the first argument to be the delimiter and the second be the string. Replace `[]` and then `explode` -

```
$var = "['test', 'test2', 'test3']";

$var = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '', $var);
$arr = explode(',', $var);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
 <?php 
 $var = "['test', 'test2', 'test3']";
 print_r(  json_decode(str_replace("'","\"",$var)) );
 ?>
```

***Output***

```
 [akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
 Array
 (
     [0] => test
     [1] => test2
     [2] => test3
 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it looks like a job for json_decode, but its not valid json... There is a way to make it valid however:

[How to json_decode invalid JSON with apostrophe instead of quotation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348380/how-to-json-decode-invalid-json-with-apostrophe-instead-of-quotation-mark)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `eval()` function in PHP which converts string into PHP statements. The string has to be valid PHP statement.

In your case `"['test', 'test2', 'test3']";` is not valid statement. You can use something similar to below syntax. Please note that the $x is in single quotes as $x in double quotes will return the value.

`$var = "['test', 'test2', 'test3'];";
eval('$x = ' . $var);
print_r($x);`

Comment: Then just pray that this isn't input from a user or 3rd party. I wouldn't use eval for this.

Comment: Yea that's true; it could be vulnerable to attacks if the string is user input and not sanitized properly.