# How do i decode multiple json object in a single string?

Tags: php, json, api

i have this string type variable

```
$product = "[{'id':'1','variant_id':'86','qty':'2','note':'dont have any'},{'id':'2','variant_id':'2','qty':'2','note':'ok'}]";
```

from the payload i get from postman request, and i want to do the foreach loop to get the item i need

and when i tried to decode it like this

```
$product = json_decode($product,true);
return $product;
```

the result is empty / null, is there something wrong with my json string?

by the way here is the postman body

```
{
"key":"cart",
"method":"post",
"payload": "{\"user_id\":\"1\",\"store_id\":\"1\",\"note\":\"okeee\",\"uuid\":\"{{uuid}}\",\"product\":\"[{'id':'1','variant_id':'86','qty':'2','note':'dont have any'},{'id':'2','variant_id':'2','qty':'2','note':'ok'}]\"}"
}
```

Comment: `return $product;` will return response. probably you need `print_r()` or `var_dump()`

Comment: your 'product' string is not [JSON](https://jsonlint.com).  Your single quotes should be double-quotes. When that is fixed, read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348380/how-to-json-decode-invalid-json-with-apostrophe-instead-of-quotation-mark).

Comment: The first sample isn't JSON, it's JSOL/JSON5. You'll need a non-standard extractor.

Comment: Valid json and response to print : https://3v4l.org/cUob8

Comment: thx you everyone